# Create a Process to assign Leads to User according to Users Closed/Won Opportunities

Tags: trigger, assignment-rules

wich one would be the best approach? was thinking to make a trigger but how can i check and count the won Opportunities for each Vendor user?

Answer (score 0):

Using a Flow would simply leave too many opportunities for gaps in the logic, and at a certain point, would probably cause performance issues. Instead, consider just writing a trigger, which would probably only be as complicated as about a dozen lines of code, depending on what you're trying to do specifically. Flows are really nice for doing simple updates, but I think this is probably a little too complicated to be built efficiently using a Flow.